# Getting names to show in dropdown list with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.2

I want to show the names of all our project leaders in a dropdown list.

The project leaders are only some of the employees that work in the company.

Here are my tables:

```
project_leaders
,----,----------------,
| id | hr_employee_id |
|----|----------------|
| 1  |  18            |
'----'----------------'

projects
,----,------,-------------------,
| id | name | project_leader_id |
|----|------|-------------------|
| 1  | cake |         1         |
'----'------'-------------------'

hr_employees
,----,------,---------,
| id | name | surname |
|----|------|---------|
| 18 | joe  | dirt    |
'----'------'---------'
```

My ProjectsController looks like this:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Project->create();
        if ($this->Project->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->_sendProjectRequestEmail($this->Project->getLastInsertID() );
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The project has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The project could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('projectLeaders',$this->Project->ProjectLeader->find('list');
}
```

This only returns the id of the Project Leaders, not the name and surname. So instead of Joe Dirt, it returns 1.

I've tried doing $this->Project->ProjectLeader->HrEmployee->find('list') but that lists all the employees.

I've also tried specifying the fields, but it returns a unknown field error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using an ActiveRecord based ORM for something like this.

Comment: Don't use `getLastInsertID()` - use `$this->ModelName->id`. also, why the `hr_` prefix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$this->set('projectLeaders',$this->Project->ProjectLeader->find('list'));
```

This will just list the records from the `project_leaders` table and most likely, as the table doesn't itself contain a name/title field (which cake would pick up automatically as the `displayField`) be like so:

```
array(
    1 => 1
)
```

### Use an appropriate find

To get a meaningful list of project leaders, you need to ensure you get a join between `project_leaders` and `hr_employees` one way to do that is using the [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior and simply specifying which fields to use in the list:

```
$projectLeaders = $this->Project->ProjectLeader->find('list', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'HrEmployee'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'ProjectLeader.id',
        'HrEmployee.name',
    )
));
$this->set(compact('projectLeaders'));
```

### Is your db structure appropriate for your needs?

Having a table equivalent to saying "this user is admin" may not be the best idea - it would be easier to avoid data problems, and give you simpler queries, if the table `project_leaders` was (only) a boolean field on your `hr_employees` table and `project_leader_id` pointed at the `hr_employee` table, *not* some other data-abstraction.

Of course I don't know your whole schema, there very well may be a good reason for having a seperate `project_leaders` table.

### Alternatively - denormalize

If you add a name field to `project_leaders` - you don't need a join to know the name of a project leader or any funkiness:

```
alter table project_leaders add name varchar(255) after id;
update project_leaders set name = (select name from hr_employees where hr_employees.id = hr_employee_id);
```

In this way you can know who is the relevant project lead with one query/join instead of needing to do two joins to get an employee's name.

Comment: Hi, with regards to the Is your db structure appropriate for your needs. The project_leaders table is necessary because one person can be the leader of various projects, but not all of them. So let's say joe is leader of project 1 2 and 3, and bob is leader of projects 4 and 5. Does this assist in understanding of the structure?

Comment: Your approach regarding the containable behaviour returns a field not found error, even though it exists in the database.

Comment: @DarkRanger if there's only one leader per project - that's one field in your project table (leader_id -> employee). If you're getting errors using the containable behavior - refer to the documentation for the containable behavior.

Comment: that's true, there is only one leader per project, but that leader can only be picked from a list of possible leaders (project_leaders). I've read through the documentation, but can't find out why it does not work.

Comment: @DarkRanger my comments about db structure are intended to make you think, I'm not saying it's wrong (you yourself may conclude that, depending on other factors). However, having an "I am a leader" boolean field in employees, and a `project_leader_id` field in projects, is, well, simpler. The most common causes of what you're now describing are: 1) model file misnamed - you aren't loading your model file at all - put a blatant parse error in it does your app crash? 2) not having loaded the containable behavior. Apart from that I suggest the irc channel, comments aren't for this kind of help.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean by having a boolean field. I'll take that approach. It is after all much simpler... :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the displayField:

The default case is

```
public $displayField = 'name';
```

And only for an existing "name"/"title" field in this table cake will automatically know what your drop-downs should get as label text.
To use the fields of other tables, make sure you pass `fields` in your find() options:

```
'fields' => array('Project.id', 'Project.name');
```

etc. Cake will then know: the first one is the key, and the second one the display value.

If you need combined/custom fields/texts in your dropdowns use virtualFields

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(...)'
);
```

and set the displayField to this `full_name` virtual field then or use `fields` as explained above.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I do that it just says: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'HrEmployee.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Make sure you also "contain" those related tables (using ContainableBehavior). Without the joins those fields will not be available, of course. You could also raise the recursive level, but thats not a very clean way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a virtual field to your ProjectLeader Model:

```
public $virtualFields = array (
'name' => 'SELECT name FROM hr_employees AS Employee WHERE Employee.id = ProjectLeader.employee_id'
);
```

Also, add this virtual field as your displayField:

```
public $displayField = 'name';
```

Comment: If you need the full name of the employee, you can use a CONCAT(...) on the SELECT clause.